# Force Android app to use a particular intent, rather than showing intent menu

Tags: android, android-intent, amazon-fire-tv

I'm working on a Fire TV app, and want to deep link to some of our other apps in their store. This can be done using amzn:// links instead of http:// but it brings up an intent menu to choose either the app store app or kindle app to complete the action.

Is there any way to force it to use a single intent (the app store), and not show the menu, or is it simply a feature of Android that it must be done this way in order to allow the user more flexibility?

Comment: If you want to open a particular App, you can craft an intent to open a specific App.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are sure that application which should get your intent is exist in a system, you can use [Intent.setClass](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E)) method

Comment: In this particular case the app should always exist, so I'll take a look into this. Thanks